# Trying to call a friend function of template class

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I have a template, in which I have a declaration of a friend function, And lower, outside the class i have it's realization:

```
template<class TreeElement, class Comparator, class Operation>
class AVLTree {
public:
     template<class A, class B, class C >
     friend AVLTree<A, B, C> createEmptyAVLTree(int n);
...
}
template<class A, class B, class C>
AVLTree<A, B, C> createEmptyAVLTree(int n) { ... }
```

What is the signature to call it somewhere in other files ?

I've tried:

```
AVLTree<Post, postByLikesFunc, emptyFunc>::createEmptyTree();
```

but it says it couldn't resolve it. Why ? Friend member should be seen just like that, aren't they ?

**EDIT:**

```
AVLTree<Post, postByLikesFunc, emptyFunc> empty;
empty = createEmptyTreeAVLTree<Post, postByLikesFunc, emptyFunc>(size);
empty.arrayToTree(sorted_posts);
```

that's in Troll.cpp in it's function.

Still shouts "was not declared in this scope", " Function could not resolved", "Symbol couldnt not resolved", "expected primary-expression before ,", "expected primary-expression before >"

Comment: solved it. just like Slardar said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVL.hpp

```
#ifndef AVL_hpp
#define AVL_hpp

template<class T1, class T2, class T3>
class AVLTree {
public:

    template<class A, class B, class C>
    friend AVLTree<A, B, C> createEmptyAVLTree(int n);
};

template<class A, class B, class C>
AVLTree<A, B, C> createEmptyAVLTree(int n) {
    return AVLTree<A,B,C>();
}

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "AVL.hpp"

int main() {
    createEmptyAVLTree<int, int, int>(4);
    return 0;
}
```

The createEmptyAVLTree isn't in the scope of AVLTree.

Comment: ok, and if main in other file ? That's what i've did right now and in other file it still "couldn't be resolved"

Comment: @KittyT2016 It works too. Can you show me more code?

Comment: @KittyT2016 And it's createEmptyAVLTree rather than createEmptyTree

Comment: I use it in another object in it's function. Updated the errors list, still almost same problem.